# Postgres Query Optimization w/ simple join

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I have the following query:

```
SELECT "person_dimensions"."dimension" 
FROM   "person_dimensions" 
join   users 
on     users.id = person_dimensions.user_id 
where  users.team_id = 2
```

The following is the result of EXPLAIN ANALYZE:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.43..93033.84 rows=452 width=11) (actual time=1245.321..42915.426 rows=827 loops=1)
      ->  Seq Scan on person_dimensions  (cost=0.00..254.72 rows=13772 width=15) (actual time=0.022..9.907 rows=13772 loops=1)
      ->  Index Scan using users_pkey on users  (cost=0.43..6.73 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=2.978..3.114 rows=0 loops=13772)
            Index Cond: (id = person_dimensions.user_id)
            Filter: (team_id = 2)
            Rows Removed by Filter: 1
Planning time: 0.396 ms
Execution time: 42915.678 ms
```

Indexes exist on person_dimensions.user_id and users.team_id, so it is unclear as to why this seemingly simple query would be taking so long.

Maybe it has something to do with team_id being unable to be used in the join condition? Ideas how to speed this up?

EDIT:

I tried this query:

```
SELECT "person_dimensions"."dimension" 
FROM "person_dimensions"
join users ON users.id = person_dimensions.user_id 
WHERE users.id IN (2337,2654,3501,56,4373,1060,3170,97,4629,41,3175,4541,2827)
```

which contains the id's returned by the subquery:

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE team_id = 2
```

The result was 380ms versus 42s as above. I could use this as a workaround, but I am really curious as to what is going on here...

Comment: `users.id`  also indexed ?

Comment: users.id is the primary key

Comment: What is the datatype of users.id and person_dimensions.user_id? If they are long (in terms of bytes) or different from each other, that is likely the source of your trouble.

Comment: @WillemRenzema I just verified and they are both integer type.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like missing statistics. Does running `analyze users;` and `analyze persons_dimensions;` change anything?

Comment: Also: which Postgres version is this? And what is the execution plan for the second query?

Comment: Also: try an index on `users (team_id, id)`

Comment: I do have an index on users (team_id, id). Sorry, forgot to mention that earlier. Will try analyze on the tables.

Comment: Postgres version is 9.5, I'll add the execution plan into an EDIT above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138576/discussion-between-bryanp-and-a-horse-with-no-name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rebooted my DB server yesterday, and when it came back up this same query was performing as expected with a completely different query plan that used expected indices:

```
QUERY PLAN
Hash Join  (cost=1135.63..1443.45 rows=84 width=11) (actual time=0.354..6.312 rows=835 loops=1)
  Hash Cond: (person_dimensions.user_id = users.id)
  ->  Seq Scan on person_dimensions  (cost=0.00..255.17 rows=13817 width=15) (actual time=0.002..2.764 rows=13902 loops=1)
  ->  Hash  (cost=1132.96..1132.96 rows=214 width=4) (actual time=0.175..0.175 rows=60 loops=1)
        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 11kB
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on users  (cost=286.07..1132.96 rows=214 width=4) (actual time=0.032..0.157 rows=60 loops=1)
              Recheck Cond: (team_id = 2)
              Heap Blocks: exact=68
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_users_on_team_id  (cost=0.00..286.02 rows=214 width=0) (actual time=0.021..0.021 rows=82 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (team_id = 2)
Planning time: 0.215 ms
Execution time: 6.474 ms
```

Anyone have any ideas why it required a reboot to be aware of all of this? Could it be that manual vacuums were required that hadn't been done in a while, or something like this? Recall I did do an analyze on the relevant tables before the reboot and it didn't change anything.